# Does struct field declaration order matter in Rust?

Tags: c, memory, struct, rust

I know that in C the compiler is not allowed to reorder struct fields and that this is important to the memory layout and alignment of the struct.

I am a beginner in Rust, and since it seems that for the most part raw pointers are hidden (I know you can still use them) if rustc is allowed to reorder the fields from their declared order in a struct.

Comment: My guess would be no, since `unsafe` code can still see the difference and since you need particular layout to interface with functions written in other languages, which Rust supports linking with. But I'm not sufficiently familiar with Rust to know for sure.

Comment: Unlike in C, Rust structure fields order is not guaranteed, unless it is `repr(C)`. Read more [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Rust Reference [Struct Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/struct.html):

> The memory layout of a `struct` is undefined by default to allow for compiler optimizations like field reordering, but it can be fixed with the [`repr` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#representations). In either case, fields may be given in any order in a corresponding struct *expression*; the resulting `struct` value will always have the same memory layout.

Comment: Could you also mention `repr(C)`, in which case the field order does indeed matter? I think that's an important detail.

Comment: ? It's right there in the quote `but it [the memory layout of a struct] can be fixed with the repr attribute`

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I think it would still be beneficial to explicitly explain `repr(C)`. I also think the second sentence in the quote is a bit confusing :/